# aggregate exceptions with entity framework in dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, dll

At work we are looking to move to an ORM (still using an access database with ADO!) I started building with entity framework and everything was going smoothly until I separated it off into it's own .dll (so we could have the website/crm/production/barcoding systems all using the same database logic).

The issue comes with handling the DbEntityValidationExceptions, my initial test code (which worked)

```
public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
        {
            try{return base.SaveChanges(options);}
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                            validationError.PropertyName,
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                //handle here
                throw;
            } 
        }
```

but this doesn't get caught now and i'm left handling a generic threadException. Is there any way to access the original data (cast the threadException?) or is there a different approach I should take.  I think I just need a push in the right direction and I can figure something out.

Regards, Pete

UPDATE:

Hmm bit of an issue calling the GetValidationErrors.  I notice that my database Context has the baseClass of ObjectContext and not DbContext (So I can't call the ValidateEntity).  I'm using Entity Framework 5 with default code generation enabled - using a database first approach if that helps.

Comment: What does the thread exception contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for validation errors before calling `SaveChanges`. Something like...

```
var errors = context.GetValidationErrors();
if(errors.Any())
{
   //handle validation errors
}
else
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

from memory, so the exact syntax may not be correct.

Comment: Ok thanks for this, I will try out yours and Jens suggestions shortly and see!

Comment: After reading some more - it seems that the ValidateEntity method is only available to the DbContext. So I guess I either figure out a way to get the default code generation to give me DbContext or stick with ObjectContext and write my own methods to validate the entities.

Comment: Using the Entity Framework power tools I was able to reverse engineer the Database first approach and create the DbContext. I used a similar method to this to catch them all. I will post the completed code once done, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I ended up going with in the end (i'll probably end up fleshing it out as I learn more about EF)

```
        public List<DbEntityValidationException> vErrors = new List<DbEntityValidationException>();
        public int DbChanges = 0;      

        public bool SaveChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                this.vErrors = (List<DbEntityValidationException>)base.GetValidationErrors();
                if (this.vErrors.Count == 0)
                {
                    this.DbChanges = base.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                this.vErrors.Add(new DbEntityValidationException(string.Format("General Error: {0}", Ex.GetType().ToString())));
            }
            return false;
        }
```

and from code

```
using(Db db = new Db())
{
//changes
if(db.SaveChanges)
{
   //some message using db.DbChanges 
}
else
{
    //handle errors in db.vErrors
}
```